# How to extract text from HTML without concatenating it using Nokogiri and Ruby

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, html-parsing, nokogiri

I have a page that has a list of people: their name, location, and a link to their profile. From this page, I want to create an array of hashes with each individual's information:

```
[{:name => 'name', :location => 'location', :link => 'link'}]
```

I am incorporating this into a scraper class, so what I have so far is:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'pry'

class Scraper
    def scrape_page('my_url')
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('my.url/'))
    students = []
    end
end
```

The plan is to set up the hashes and insert them into the `students` array. Starting with the names here's how I go about it:

```
doc.css('div.name-header h4').children.map.to_a
```

Which returns:

```
[#(Text "Bob Charlie"),
 #(Text "Glass Joe"),
 #(Text "Piston Hurricane"),
 #(Text "Big Bear Hugger"),
   ...]
```

I haven't figured out how to target just the text inside the XML element, because any method I use that actually returns the text does it so that the previous individual's last name and the following individual's first name are not separated by a space and it's one long string:

```
"Bob CharlieGlass JoePiston HurricaneBig Bear Hugger  ... "
```

I managed to get around it like this:

```
doc.css('div.name-header h4').children.to_a.join("\n").split("\n").zip
```

Is there a way to simply target that text directly in order to pipe each one directly into an array?

Comment: have you tried `map(&:text)` ?

Comment: Whoa that did it! Where could I have found that information for future reference? I've already gone over the tutorials and cheat sheet and everything. 

Thank you, that's a big help.

Comment: [Docs for Nokogiri::XML::Node#content](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#content-instance_method) `#text` is an alias for `#content`. [Cheat Sheet Working with a Nokogiri::XML::Node](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/Cheat-sheet#working-with-a-nokogirixmlnode) see "## Content / Children" at the bottom of that section

Comment: When asking, we need to see the minimum code and HTML or XML in the question that demonstrates the problem. See "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".